# Oneboxes of bookmarked chat conversations overflow on to the side

Tags: bug, design, chat, onebox, chat-bookmarks

A bookmarked chat conversation's onebox overflows onto the side when the screen is skinny:

[image: a few chat messages, where the onebox of a question resizes properly and the onebox of a conversation does not]

As you can see, other kinds of oneboxes (there's a question there) resize properly. However the white box of a conversation's onebox overflows off the right side. [Similar behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pILaK.png) is observed in [the transcript](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59401955#59401955). Could this be fixed so the conversation onebox resizes like the question onebox?

<sub>If you're wondering what all the other links are from, I tested a few old onebox-related bug reports while checking for duplicates</sub>